# .Net 4 CAS - Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.WebPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Action: Demand

Tags: .net, permissions, cas

My build server runs a SpecFlow acceptance test DLL through Gallio.

This calls a WCF service and performs our acceptance tests.

Running locally works fine.

However on the build server (even with Cruise Control running under my account)

I keep getting

System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.WebPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
Action: Demand

This build server is running .Net 4.

Is there anyway to switch CAS off?

Thanks