# Request for the permission failed from a desktop app running on a network drive

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, permissions, code-access-security

The following exception is raised when opening a WCF client from a .NET 4 desktop application. This only seems to be happening at one of our client installations:

`Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.WebPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed`

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: reffer :same problem fixed !!! http://stackoverflow.com/a/39073784/6742494

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interestingly here's another (unanswered) SO from someone getting the same problem from CruiseControl: [.Net 4 CAS - Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.WebPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Action: Demand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222420/net-4-cas-request-for-the-permission-of-type-system-net-webpermission-syste).  It's possible that this'll end up being a dupe; but that's unfair at the moment since that's not been answered.

This seems similar to the pre 3.5 sp1 network security woes, where applications runs from a network location would be denied many permissions through CAS.

I think this blog post might provide the solution, although it might not apply if the executable itself is loaded from a remote location (check the first solution) http://www.damirscorner.com/CodeAccessSecurityStrikesBackInNET4.aspx

Although, also looking at [Exploring the .Net Framework 4 Security Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee677170.aspx) (which provides the same workarounds as the aforementioned blog post) it might not apply, as it implies that unhosted Exes run from network locations should run fully-trusted by default - when clearly yours aren't!

One thing to try if this doesn't work is to make the exe (and by extension all it's references) strong-named.

Comment: Thanks Andras - I'll take a look. The exe and and dll files are all strong-named.

Answer (score 0):

Having read Andras's answer and checked some other applications we provide to clients, it seems the following code in the app.config file *could* sort the issue (as it's present in our other applications but not the one we're having an issue with):

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" />
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: did this solve the problem for you? I'm having a similar issue.