# How to request a permission of type System.Net.WebPermission in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, razor

I created a small web service that creates a `HttpWebRequest` to another website using a proxy 
and after i used the proxies i got that error:

> Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.WebPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

I have no idea about how to fix it.

Here is my code,

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://website.com");
req.CookieContainer = c;

req.Proxy = new WebProxy("IP:PORT");

req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; GTB7.4; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.2)";
req.Accept = "application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*";
req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US");
req.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
req.Timeout = 10000;
req.Method = "GET";
req.KeepAlive = true;
req.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are running into a *trust* related issue. You might be able to work-around the issue by including in your `Web.Config`, under `System.Web`,

```
<trust level="Full" />
```

`WebPermission` is not available under a `medium trust` environment (and you can look at [this article](http://blogs.iis.net/hosterposter/archive/2006/03/22/Enabling-WebPermission-in-Medium-Trust.aspx) to modify this behavior and for the reasons why you shouldn't).

However, if you require `full trust` you might have to reconsider the requirements of your application.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work :(
i tried that on my localhost and it works but once i upload it to my web hosting it doesn't work

Comment: That's what I meant by *you might have to reconsider the requirements*: this setting will work on your development environment (since it is already running with Admin privileges), but it will fail when deploy to a restricted environment (and most are). What you are trying to is *not* possible from a security point of view as it will open a huge loophole in the target system (giving NetworkService `full trust`).

Comment: This answer is correct, but the way I changed trust was to right click on your project... properties... Security.. Click "This is a Full Trust Application". I can't exactly say what that will do to security in the long term. It fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

go to properties of your Project/application  (WPF)

In security select enable clickone securitysetting. and set trust level of the project

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this issue - and it turned out to be due to dll performing the web request having being downloaded from the web.

I had to go into the Properties of the dll in file explorer (right click> Properties) and click "Unblock" - making sure to click "Apply" and then "Ok".